# using stackage on windows

Tags: windows, haskell, stackage

I am trying to use stackage on windows. I cloned the git repo, ran `cabal install --only-dependencies`, `cabal configure`, `cabal build`. Everything works

then `dist\build\Stackage\stackage.exe select`

```
Loading Haskell Platform
Loading package database
Narrowing package database
Printing build plan to build-plan.log
Checking for bad versions
authenticate-oauth-1.4.0.8 (FP Complete <michael@fpcomplete.com> @yesodweb) cannot use:
- RSA-2.0 -- ==1.2.*

threepenny-gui-0.4.1.0 (FP Complete <michael@fpcomplete.com>) cannot use:
- aeson-0.7.0.2 -- ==0.6.*

stackage.exe: Conflicting build plan, exiting
```

the readme mention *.sh scripts like `./patching/scripts/create-tarballs.sh`. I tried but failed to run them with cygwin. Are they important?

How can I use stackage on windows?

**edit** I was able to run the `./patching/scripts/create-tarballs.sh` script using msys. But now the error message is:

```
Loading Haskell Platform
Loading package database
stackage.exe: Missing cabal file "MFlow-0.3.3/MFlow.cabal" in tarball: "patching/tarballs\\MFlow-0.3.3.tar.gz"
```

I checked the archive: the cabal file is inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows users are not recommended to install stackage by Haskell Platform installer due to some limitation:

1. On Windows, it does not provide a complete environment (missing MSYS).
2. By placing a large number of packages in the global package database, Haskell Platform installations are more easily corrupted.
3. The choice of package versions conflicts with the needs of many commonly used packages.
4. Some of the package versions included with the platform have known and severe bugs, and cannot be reliably upgraded.

As for solution to overcome, uninstall the Haskell platform first, then install minghc for windows by the following link: https://github.com/fpco/minghc#readme

Open command prompt run `cabal update` and `cabal install alex happy`.
Finally, install stackage.

---

### Update 2015

A new tool has been developed by Commercial Haskell group for project development -- [Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html), it can be install along with the latest Haskell Platform (7.10.2).

Features include:

- Installing GHC automatically, in an isolated location.
- Installing packages needed for your project.
- Building your project.
- Testing your project.
- Benchmarking your project.

I have tried it for haskell web project, it works smoothly.